# How to Create a Curved bottom Container in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm really new to Flutter, I'm trying to replicate the design in this image [See sample image right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq6QO.jpg)  my problem is how to make the bottom of the image curved as it appears in the photo... Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code

```
Container(
    height: 200.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          bottom: Radius.elliptical(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100.0)),
    ),
  ),
```

or you can use CustomPainter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ProfileScreen(),
    );
  }
}

// class to draw the profile screen
class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffea5d49),
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
              painter: HeaderCurvedContainer(),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    // image: DecorationImage(
                    //   image: AssetImage(null),
                    //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    // ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CustomPainter class to for the header curved-container
class HeaderCurvedContainer extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = const Color(0xffea5d49);
    Path path = Path()
      ..relativeLineTo(0, 150)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, 250.0, size.width, 150)
      ..relativeLineTo(0, -150)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can try with CustomClipper class

```
  ClipPath(
   clipper: CurveImage(),
   child: Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     height: 300,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
             fit: BoxFit.fill,
             image: NetworkImage(
                 "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRjHtidokLaIsJlVNVtCk_DJXAIvPJyvTFnYA&usqp=CAU"))
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

In the above code I called one custom clipper object name **CurveImage()** it will help you to convert your image into a curve shape.

**CLass**

```
 class CurveImage extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height-30);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, size.height,
        size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - (size.width / 4), size.height,
        size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this package, [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers), with many custom shape, use of ease